# Error al escribir un espacio al ingresar equipos (en C)

Tags: c, nodos

estoy comenzando un proyecto de la universidad pero en el caso 1 del menu que es para agergar equipos e id´s no puedo insertar espacios como por ejemplo, si escribo "real madrid", automaticamente vuelve a lanzar el menu, pero si escribo solo "real" sí me pregunta el id y todo va correctamente. Creo que es un error en el scanf, en la manera en que declaré mis variables o incluso en el void donde agrego un nuevo nodo. Alguien me podría ayudar por favor?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



struct nodo
{
char *equipos;
int id;
struct nodo *next;
};

struct nodo *head = NULL;
struct nodo *tail = NULL;

void add_tail (char *string, int d)
{
//Crear nodo, c
struct nodo *p = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
p->equipos=string;
p->id=d;

if (head == NULL && tail == NULL)
{
head = p;
tail = p;
}
else
{
tail->next = p;
tail = p;
}
p->next = NULL;
}


int main()
{
int opcion = 0;
int i;

while (opcion != 4)
{
printf("1. Ingreso de equipos \n");
printf("2. Lista equipos \n");
printf("3. Ingreso de resultados \n");
printf("4. Salir\n");

scanf("%d", &opcion);

switch(opcion)
{
  case 1:
switch(opcion)
{
  case 1:
  {
    int d;
    char string[255];
    printf("Ingrese equipo a almacenar: \n");
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("Ingrese id del equipo: \n");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    add_tail (string, d);
  break;
  }
  case 2:
  {
    print();
    break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparte de errores varios en tu código, como que está incompleto (falta cerrar varias llaves), centrándonos en el asunto por el que preguntas, lo que ocurre es que `scanf()` solo lee palabras individuales, no puede leer "frases" que contengan espacios, pues se detiene en cuanto encuentra el primer espacio.

Una solución es usar `gets()`, que puede leer una línea completa (deneniéndose sólo al llegar al retorno de carro que también lee). Mejor aún, usar `fgets()` a la que se le puede pasar también el número máximo de caracteres a leer, para evitar desbordamiento de buffers.

No obstante, vas a tener quebraderos de cabeza si en el mismo programa mezclas `fgets()` para leer cadenas, con `scanf()` para leer números, como ocurre en tu caso. La razón de estos quebraderos de cabeza es que `scanf()` no lee los retornos de carro que haya al final de la entrada, con lo que puedes encontrar la siguiente situación:

1. Muestras un mensaje en el que se pide al usuario un entero
2. Lees el entero con algo como `scanf("%d", &opcion)`
3. El usuario teclea un número (ej: el 1) y pulsa retorno de carro
4. `scanf()` lee el 1 y lo almacena en `opcion`, pero deja sin leer el retorno de carro que queda en el buffer de teclado "esperando" a ser leido por el próximo `scanf()`. Si efectivamente hicieras un `scanf()` a continuación, éste lo primero que encontraría sería un `\n` que leería e ignoraría, y se quedaría a la espera de más caracteres.
5. Mostramos al usuario un mensaje pidiéndole que introduzca texto.
6. Pero en vez de un `scanf()` hacemos un `fgets()` para leer una línea de texto, que pueda contener espacios. Entonces....
7. `fgets()` encuentra el `\n` que había dejado allí sin leer el `scanf()` previo, pero no lo ignora, sino que considera que es todo lo que hay para leer y retorna eso: una línea vacía con solo un retorno de carro al final. Y eso sin dar oportunidad al usuario de escribir nada
8. El usuario ve como el programa sigue sin que él haya escrito nada. No funciona como se esperaba

Una solución a este problema es "tragar" el `\n` que estaba pendiente de ser leido, antes de invocar a `fgets()`. Por ejemplo, puedes hacer una llamada a `getc()` justo tras leer el entero en el paso 2.

Esta solución sería así:

```
int n;
char buff[200];
printf("Introduce un entero: ");
scanf("%d", &n);  // Leemos el entero
getc();           // Consumimos un carácter más (el retorno de carro sin leer)

printf("Ahora introduce una cadena (puede contener espacios): ");
fgets(buff, 199, stdin);

printf("Entero introducido: %d\n", n);
printf("Cadena introducida: '%s'\n", buff);
```

Si ejecutas este ejemplo verás que la cadena introducida contiene también el `\n` del final de línea. Si no lo quieres puedes hacer `buff[strlen(buff)] = 0` para eliminarlo.